# Put json return value from ajax in one or more text box

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$('select[name=\'service_id\']').bind('change', function() {

    service_id = $('select[name=\'service_id\']').val();

    $.ajax({

        url: 'myajaxfile.php&service_id=' +  service_id,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(json) {

            var max_use = json.max_use;
            var used = json.used;
            var amount = json.amount;

            $('input[name=\'max_use\']').val(max_use);
            $('input[name=\'used\']').val(amount);

        }
    });
});
```

Above is my piece of code. All I want is to bind the value from json result which is coming fine to two or more text boxes which is not happening. The json result is like `[{"max_use":"0","period":"30","amount":"99"}]` which is very correct. On doing an alert to amount it says undefined. Would be great help if point me out what's the problem is? I tried searching on stackoverflow but found no perfect solution that works. Thanks.

Comment: would you please help me for that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json is an array with an object in it. So you must either change json, or access object properties like that:

```
var max_use = json[0].max_use;
var used = json[0].used;
var amount = json[0].amount;
```

proper json in your case would look like that:

```
{"max_use":"0","period":"30","amount":"99"}
```

without []

Answer (score 4):

try

```
var t = JSON.parse(json);

 var max_use = t[0]["max_use"];
 var used = t[0]["used"];
 var amount = t[0]["amount"];
```

Comment: gave an error JSON parse:: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
 

var t = JSON.parse(json);

Comment: ajax dataType is set to "json", so json variable contains object, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

result is an array, you have value at 0 index, so use as below

```
result  = [{"max_use":"0","period":"30","amount":"99"}][0]
```

fetch as below

```
result.max_user
result.period
result.amount
```

or

```
result["max_user"]
result["period"]
result["amount"]
```